# Residue, last step

Tags: residue-calculus

I'm doing some fouriertransform, and can't get the last step correct when Im comparing to an old exam with the question.

Its the fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+7x^2}$.

Where my solution is wrong is when I compute the actual residue.

My solution, a couple of steps in:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+7z^2} \Rightarrow z= \pm \frac{i}{\sqrt{7}}$ where $\frac{i}{\sqrt{7}} \in int(\gamma_R)$ and the residue we want to calculate.

I would like to say that the residue is $\lim_{z \rightarrow \frac{i}{\sqrt{7}}} (z-\frac{i}{\sqrt{7}}) \frac{e^{-izt}}{(z-\frac{I}{\sqrt{7}}(z+\frac{I}{\sqrt{7}})}$

This is the step that I cant get right, and its just simple algebra...

My answer of above is $\frac{\sqrt{7}e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{7}}}}{2i}$

While the correct answer according to the exam $\frac{e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{7}}}}{2i\sqrt{7}}$

Can someone show me the actual steps on how this is correct, I know its a rather simple question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+7z^2}$$

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{1+7z^2} &= \frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{(\frac{i}{7}+z^2)}\\
&= \ldots
\end{eqnarray}

When you then apply your residue you have
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Res}_{z=i/\sqrt{7}} & =\frac{1}{7}\frac{e^{t/\sqrt{7}}}{2i/\sqrt{7}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{7}}{14i}e^{t/\sqrt{7}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{7}}e^{t/\sqrt{7}}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks! Looking at your solution I realise that, when finding roots, I simply divided by 7 when $7z^2=-1$ without multiplying it back, which gave me the right roots but the 7 disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: @zzz__ Precisely, easy mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to find the residue at $i/\sqrt 7$ $$\frac{1}{7z^2+1}=\frac{1}{7(z-i\sqrt 7)(z+i\sqrt 7)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{7(z-i/\sqrt 7)((z-i/\sqrt 7)+2i/\sqrt 7)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{7(z-i/\sqrt 7)(2i/\sqrt 7)(1+(\sqrt 7/2i)(z-i/\sqrt 7))}$$ $$=\frac{-\sqrt 7\space i}{14(z-i/\sqrt 7)(1-(\sqrt 7\space i/2)(z-i/\sqrt 7))}$$ $$=\frac{-\sqrt7 \space i(1+(\sqrt 7\space i/2)(z-i/\sqrt 7)+...)}{14(z-i/\sqrt 7)}$$